# How can I change the counters of tables in the appendices?

Tags: floats, numbering, counters, appendices

I have multiple appendices and in some appendices I have tables. What I want is that each appendix itself has a letter as a number (e.g. Appendix A: title). A second thing that I want to achieve is that the table in each appendix are numbered by a letter and a number, the letter corresponding by the appendix the table is in, and number should start from 1 in each appendix. The second table in the second appendix should be numbered B2, no matter how many tables I have in the first appendix.

I am able to use letters as numbers for my appendices, but not in the correct form. I can refer to the tables in the text (but not in the correct way, I use "see Table B\ref{results}" for instance). I cannot seem to change the numbering of the tables itself. The numbering starts with 1 and adds up. I don't know how to put a letter in front of it.

Answer (score 4):

I use, for Appendix figures and tables

```
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{appndx}\@arabic\c@figure}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{appndx}\arabic{table}}
```

Then they appear as Table A1, A2, B1, etc.