# Correct numbering of figures/tables/listings in Appendix

Tags: sectioning, listings, numbering, appendices

In my thesis I have several appendices, which are defined via `\section{First Appendix}`, `\section{Second Appendix}`, etc. latex statements. The appendices have the following titles (hence, appear like this in the table of contents): *A First Appendix*, *B Second Appendix*, etc.

These appendices include listings and figures. Currently, the listings in the appendices are numbered as follows:

- A.1 First Listing of Appendix A
- A.2 Second Listing of Appendix A
- B.3 First Listing of Appendix B
- C.4 First Listing of Appendix C

However, I would like to have the following numbering (I think it's more intuitive and looks nicer):

- A.1 First Listing of Appendix A
- A.2 Second Listing of Appendix A
- B.1 First Listing of Appendix B
- C.1 First Listing of Appendix C

In other words, after each new appendix (which is defined via `\section{Second Appendix}`), I want the listings/figures/tables counter to be reset. In the main content of the thesis this is done automatically. I do not know why this is not the case in the appendix.

Note, that I use the following commands to achieve the desired numbering of figures/listings/tables which appear in the appendix:

```
\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{lstlisting}}
\renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{section}.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{section}.\arabic{figure}}
```

Comment: these comments seems related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118606/numbering-tables-a1-a2-etc-in-latex#comment759017_311998 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100829/74509

Answer (score 2):

Add the `lstlisting` counter to the reset list of the `section` counter with

`\counterwithout*{lstlisting}{section}`

-- the `*` prevents redefinition of `\thelstlisting` then!

Saying

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \counterwithin*{lstlisting}{section}%
}
\makeatother
```

this will automatically enable this specific style of resetting if `\appendix` is used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{lstlisting}}
\renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{section}.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{section}.\arabic{figure}}


}


%Automatically change the driver counter for reset:
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \counterwithin*{lstlisting}{section}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\appendix
\section{Foo}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={C},caption={Foo}]
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={C},caption={Foo}]
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}

\end{lstlisting}

\section{Foobar}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={C},caption={Foo}]
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
\end{lstlisting}

\section{More foobar}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={C},caption={Foo}]
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}


\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same "problem" with the non-intuitive numbering in my thesis. A solution (inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210378/111287)) is to reset the counter after `\appendix`, but before the first `section` and `lstlisting`.

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand\thelstlisting{\thesection.\arabic{lstlisting}}

\setcounter{lstlisting}{0}
```

Additionally, because I don't want to have to reset the counter manually for each `section`, I use `\sectionbreak` from the package [`titlesec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), which enables one to define commands before the beginning of each section. I added the counter resetting like this

```
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\setcounter{lstlisting}{0}}
```

A full MWE would like this (credits also to @Christian Hupfer)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\appendix

\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand\thelstlisting{\thesection.\arabic{lstlisting}}

\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\setcounter{lstlisting}{0}} % to reset counter for listings before each new section

\section{First appendix}
Some text.

\begin{lstlisting}[language={C},caption={Foo1}]
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main(int argc,char **argv)
    {
      printf(``Hello World!\n'');
      return(0);
    }
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={C},caption={Foo2}]
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main(int argc,char **argv)
    {
      printf(``Hello World!\n'');
      return(0);
    }
\end{lstlisting}


\section{Second appendix}
Some more text.

\begin{lstlisting}[language={C},caption={Foo3}]
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main(int argc,char **argv)
    {
      printf(``Hello World!\n'');
      return(0);
    }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Important note:** It seems you need to have *some text* within `section` to get the `\sectionbreak`working.

[image]

I'm not quite sure whether this is a solution or a workaround, but it is working for me.

Btw, this is also working for `figure` and `table`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It would be great if you could add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates how this solution works.  I tried to get your answer working but was unsuccessful, a full compilable MWE (`\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) will help others understand and appreciate your solution more easily.

Comment: +1 Thanks for adding the MWE, now I can see this works, I think I may have only had the `lstlisting` environment in each `section`.  I wonder whether that's intended on the part of `titlesec`.  Rather than `\sectionbreak` you might be able to `\apptocmd` from [`etoolbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to append the necessary instructions to the `\section` macro.